# Connecting toolbar with the navigation drawer

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, android-toolbar

I have several activities where I want to use the same navigation drawer. Here's part of my Activity class code related to the drawer:

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
toggle.syncState();
NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
```

I'm planning to make a DrawerActivity class and extend it from all those activities which want the Navigation drawer. Therefore, I will have to move all the drawer code to that DrawerActivity.

**The problem:**

`toolbar` is important for the initialization of `ActionBarDrawerToggle`. Every activity has a different toolbar depending upon the needs of that activity. Therefore, the toolbar layouts must be kept in their respective layout xml files. How would I use the toolbar then in the DrawerActivity class?

Layout xml for the drawer:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:openDrawer="start">


<FrameLayout
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/frame_layout"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

</FrameLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    app:itemBackground="@drawable/drawer_list_selector"
    style="@style/NavigationDrawer"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/sidenav_header"
    app:menu="@menu/side_navigation_menu"
    app:theme="@style/Drawer"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

---

Here's the SideNavigation activity (which I'm trying to extend by those classes who need navigation drawer): [pastebin.com/hheMXku5](http://pastebin.com/hheMXku5)

main statement of the log says:

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(boolean)' on a null object reference

Here's the link to the onCreate of one of the activity class that extends the SideNavigation class: [pastebin.com/iKYXVbda](http://pastebin.com/iKYXVbda)

Answer (score 0):

okey so as you want to use drawer with Activity. I am posting my code here. I hope this will help you out.

First of all you need to develop `NavigationDrawer`. I know you can do it by your self.

Now create child Activity for Example **Home.java** and extend it with your drawer Activity let's say `MainActivity.java`.

it will be something like this.

```
public class Home extends MainActivity{

     Toolbar toolbar;

     @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     }
}
```

Now usually we perform `setContentView` in `onCreate`, bur here do something like this.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.home, frameLayout);

    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
}
```

Where `frameLayout` would be your container, which you have take in `MainActivity`.

**Note :** don't forget to take another `ToolBar` in home Activity. because it will override MainActivity's toolbar.

**EDIT**
I am posting my Whole code please refer it. Although I have took my custom Navigation drawer but it can work with `NavigationView` too.

**activity_main**

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/frame_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="false" >

    <!-- ToolBar of MainActivity -->

    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_headers"
        layout="@layout/toolbar_header" />
</RelativeLayout>

<!-- here will be your NavigationView -->

<com.random.extraclasses.ScrimInsetsFrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:layout_marginRight="-8dp"
    android:elevation="8dp"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:insetForeground="#4000" >

    <include
        android:id="@+id/drawar_layout"
        layout="@layout/drawar_layout" />
</com.gujarat.property.extraclasses.ScrimInsetsFrameLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnClickListener {

     protected RelativeLayout frameLayout;
     protected DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
     protected ListView mDrawerList;
     protected ScrimInsetsFrameLayout mLayout;
     protected ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
     protected static boolean isLaunch = true;

     Toolbar toolbar;

     private CharSequence mTitle;

     private String[] navMenuTitles;
     private TypedArray navMenuIcons;

     private ArrayList<NavDrawerItem> navDrawerItems;
     private NavDrawerListAdapter adapter;

     @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

         navMenuTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_drawer_items);

         navMenuIcons = getResources()
            .obtainTypedArray(R.array.nav_drawer_icons);

         frameLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.frame_container);
         mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
         mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
         mLayout = (ScrimInsetsFrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.container);

         toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_headers);

         setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

         navDrawerItems = new ArrayList<NavDrawerItem>();

         navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[0], navMenuIcons
            .getResourceId(0, -1)));
         navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[1], navMenuIcons
            .getResourceId(1, -1)));
         navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[2], navMenuIcons
            .getResourceId(2, -1)));
         navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[3], navMenuIcons
            .getResourceId(3, -1)));

         navMenuIcons.recycle();

         adapter = new NavDrawerListAdapter(getApplicationContext(),
            navDrawerItems);
         mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
             @Override
             public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                     int position, long id) {
                 selectedPos = position - 1;
                 displayView(position);
             }
         });

         mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);
         mDrawerList.setFocusable(false);

         getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
         getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);  

         mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
            R.drawable.ic_drawer, R.string.app_name) {
         };
         mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

         if (isLaunch) {
             isLaunch = false;
             displayView(0);
         }

     }

     @Override
     public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
         if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
             return true;
         }
         return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
     }

     private void displayView(int position) {

         mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mLayout);
         MainActivity.position = position;
         switch (position) {

         case 0:
             if (this.getClass().getSimpleName().equals("Home")) {
             } else {
                 Intent i = new Intent(this, Home.class);
                 startActivity(i);
                 overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fadein, R.anim.fadeout);
             }
             break;
         case 1:
             if (this.getClass().getSimpleName().equals("ForSale")) {
             } else {
                 Intent i = new Intent(this, ForSale.class);
                 startActivity(i);
                 overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fadein, R.anim.fadeout);
             }
             break;
         case 2:
              if (this.getClass().getSimpleName().equals("ForRent")) {
              } else {
                 Intent i = new Intent(this, ForRent.class);
                 startActivity(i);
                 overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fadein, R.anim.fadeout);
              } 
              break;
         case 3:
             if (this.getClass().getSimpleName().equals("NewProjects")) {
             } else {
                 Intent i = new Intent(this, NewProjects.class);
                 startActivity(i);
                 overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fadein, R.anim.fadeout);
             }
             break;
          default:
             break;
         }
     }

     @Override
     public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
         mTitle = title;
         getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
     }

     @Override
     protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
         mDrawerToggle.syncState();
     }

     @Override
     public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
         super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
         mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
     }

     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {

     }
 }
```

And finally **Home.java**

```
public class Home extends MainActivity implements OnClickListener {

Toolbar toolbar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.home, frameLayout);

    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("");
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    if (mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mLayout)) {
        isLaunch = false;
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mLayout);
    } else {
        finishAffinity();
    }
}
```

And just for reference **home.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
     android:id="@+id/main"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent" >

     <RelativeLayout
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
         android:background="@drawable/back51" >

        <TextView
             android:id="@+id/etSearch"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
             android:background="@android:color/transparent"
             android:text="Search Property"
             android:textColor="#666666" />
     </RelativeLayout>

     <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
         android:id="@+id/toolbar"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
         android:background="@color/toobar"
         android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
         android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
         app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" >
     </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I hope this will help you out.

Comment: So, I declared the FrameLayout container in the main activity xml file, inflated it with the home layout, but I'm getting the NPE. I've updated the layout for main activity in the question. Any  idea why is it happening?

Comment: Getting the null pointer exception at `getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);`

Comment: Have you took another toolbar in Home layout?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get it? I already have a toolbar in my home layout. And I also have this code: `Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);` in my home activity class.

Comment: you got to change `setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false)` with `setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true)`. and if you can show me your code and log I can be able to help you out.

Comment: Thanks, I will try it and if doesn't work, I'll post the log and my code.

Comment: It still didn't work. Here's the SideNavigation activity (which we are referring as the MainActivity): http://pastebin.com/hheMXku5

and the main statement of the log says:
                                                                             `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(boolean)' on a null object reference`

Here's the link to the onCreate of the Home class:
http://pastebin.com/iKYXVbda